# iReport 3.0.0: How to compare big decimals in field expression

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, ireport, bigdecimal

Can anyone tell me how to compare two Big Decimal values in *field* expression (*textFieldExpression*)? I'm using *iReport 3.0.0*.

What is the syntax for *greater then?*

This is my expression, and it works but only shows if two values not equal, and I need to check which one is greater (`amount > paid_amount`).

I'm using this expression:

```
($F{paid_date}!=null & ($F{amount}.equals($F{paid_amount}))) ? new String ("PAID") :(
($F{paid_date}==null) ? new String ("NOT PAID"): (
($F{paid_date}!=null & (!$F{amount}.equals($F{paid_amount}))) ? new String ("PARTIALLY PAID"):(new String ("INVOICE MISSING "))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fields like this:

```xml
<field name="amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="paid_amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
```

you should use this expression:

```xml
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{amount}.compareTo($F{paid_amount}) == 1 
? "The amount value is greater than the paid_amount value" 
: $F{amount}.compareTo($F{paid_amount}) == 0 ? 
"The amount value is equal to the paid_amount value" : 
"The amount value is less than the paid_amount value"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This expression based on using ***[int BigDecimal.compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)*** method.